# Unable to find template in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, templates, bundle

I know that there are a lot of subject like that however I didn't find the solution

I have this issue

> Unable to find template "CoreBundle:index.html.twig" (looked into: /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).

This is the architecture 
[image]
This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('CoreBundle:index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/ma-personnalite", name="ma-personnalite")
     */
    public function mapersonnaliteAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('CoreBundle:ma_personnalite.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/cv", name="cv")
     */
    public function cvAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('CoreBundle:cv.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/scolaires", name="scolaires")
     */
    public function scolairesAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('CoreBundle:scolaires.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/extra-scolaires", name="extra-scolaires")
     */
    public function extrascolairesAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('CoreBundle:extra_scolaires.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/contact", name="contact")
     */
    public function contactAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('CoreBundle:contact.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This is the config.yml

```
#app/config/routing.yml
core:
    resource: "@CoreBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [Symfony 3 Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle) it's better to use slashes and to not use "Bundle" word.

So, we have as example:

```
return $this->render('@BloggerBlog/Default/index.html.twig');
```

Answer (score 4):

try to change this:

```
return $this->render('CoreBundle:index.html.twig');
```

to this:

```
return $this->render('CoreBundle::index.html.twig');
```

The difference is to use `::` instead of `:`

Comment: Thank you very much ! How can I do to include when there is a folder ? (I want to include CoreBundle/Index/_meta.html.twig)

Comment: Something like this: 'CoreBundle::example\index.html.twig I think but you need to try

Comment: You're my heroes

Comment: Ahaha glad to help you!

Answer (score 3):

This helped me in my case:
`@Core/index.html.twig`