# Unable to find template: Creating a simple Controller and view

Tags: php, symfony, routes

My controller is /src/AppBundle/Controller/TestsController.php and the class is:

```
class TestsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/tests/index", name="testsIndex")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('AppBundle::tests\index.html.twig', [
            'text' => "Hello world"
        ]);
    }
}
```

My view is /src/AppBundle/Resources/views/tests/index.html.twig and contains:

```
{{text}}
```

But when I try to open http://localhost/project/web/tests/index the error shows:

> Unable to find template "AppBundle::tests/index.html.twig" (looked
>   into: D:\www\project\app/Resources/views,
>   D:\www\project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form).

I followed this thread which error is pretty much the same but still can't find the mistake. It's driving me nuts.

[Unable to find template in Symfony 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476659/unable-to-find-template-in-symfony-3)

Thanks!

Comment: One colon after the AppBundle is all you need but that syntax is going away.  Use @App/tests/index.html.twig https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle

Comment: See the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle/47835716#47835716) if you want to know why the old format does not work and what is needed to enable it.  But again, just use the twig namespace @ format.

Comment: A thousand thanks to you, @App/tests/index.html.twig worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Should work, but try `AppBundle:tests:index.html.twig`.

You might also want to use uppercase `Tests` instead of `tests`. More conventional.

Comment: Yeah, kind of thought so... try what Cerad suggested. If that still does not work please post your structure. Is AppBundle your namespace root?

Answer (score 0):

Cerad's solution was perfectly right:

```
@App/tests/index.html.twig
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @Route("/tests/index", name="testsIndex")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('tests\index.html.twig', [
        'text' => "Hello world"
    ]);
}
```

This should work.